# font size after printing

Tags: font-size, figma

How to figure out what size the font will be after the print? I'm designing the poster A1 300 dpi, the frame size in figma is W7017 H9921. I'd like to use the font 40pt for the text. The font size, as long I understand, in Figma is given in density-independent pixels. How does it translate to pt? I don't have a printer on hand to print A1 and test it.